# What is the "right" pattern for inserting children when there is an existing parent with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am new to EF. There are plenty of examples of inserting a record in a table and inserting a Parent/Child when there is not already a parent in the table.

What is the correct pattern for inserting additional children in tables when there is already a row for the parent? Do you query for the parent first, add a new member to the child collection and save?

The code below works but just checking that this is the right approach:

```
using (var context = new Entities())
{
    var query = from t in context.Tools
                where t.ToolNumber == "Hello"
                select t;

    if (query.Any())
    {
       query.FirstOrDefault().FirstParts.Add( new FirstPart() { DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString() } );
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the wrong forum for this type of question.  here on SO we are answering questions related to exceptions, etc.  however it seems your code is simply adding a child to the first parent returned (`FirstOrDefault`) - not sure if that was intended.

Comment: Yes. The code was intended to show a basic flow of looking for an entry in the parent table and if found then add a new record to the child table. It is not complete code but a snippet.

Comment: i few minutes spent here will give a large return on investment :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: @johnb Thanks for that link. Looking at this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  I do not see anything that would indicate that my question is out of bounds for stack overflow. I do not see where I am limited to just asking questions about exceptions, etc. I have searched for hours on the question i asked. It is clearly worded, about a problem. How am I violating this set of rules on this page? Just trying to understand so I can be asking better questions in the future.

Comment: here are a couple of links: the [tour], [ask]